# How to get SubnetIds in DB subnetgroup in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've created two DB subnets and created a DB Subnet Group in cloud formation, In DBSubnetGroup how do i add SubnetIds as the subnet id's are created during run time and how do i fetch them here, please can any one help me with this, thanks in advance

```
      "ADBSubnetGroup" : {
     "Type" : "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup",
     "Properties" : {
     "DBSubnetGroupDescription" : "Subnet group for DB subnets in two  AZ",
     "SubnetIds" : [  ],
     "Tags" : [ {"Key" : "Name", "Value" : "ADBSubnetGroup"} ]
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like below,

```
"ADBSubnetGroup" : {
     "Type" : "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup",
     "Properties" : {
     "DBSubnetGroupDescription" : "Subnet group for DB subnets in two  AZ",
     "SubnetIds" : [{"Ref": "dbprivatesubnet01"},{ "Ref" : "dbprivatesubnet02"}  ],
     "Tags" : [ {"Key" : "Name", "Value" : "ADBSubnetGroup"} ]
     }
  }
```

It will help you to set a subnet with two AZs.